# 'undefined columns selected' when switching from 2 'for loops' to 'outer'

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 tables: `freq.table` has the distribution of types per land, `match.table` says which types match

```
#freq.table               #match.table
       typeA  typeB   |         typeA typeB  
aland   30.0   70.0   |   typeA  TRUE  TRUE
bland   70.0   30.0   |   typeB  TRUE FALSE
```

Now I want a new table like `freq.table` but with different values:
For each point in `freq` (country, type), the new value should be the sum of all (country,type_m) where (type,type_m) is TRUE in match.table.
One could also say I want to merge `freq[country,]` and `match[type,]`
matching types' frequencies but only the columns where `match` is `TRUE`.
So in `matches` I store the matching types and `freq[country,matches]` gives me all frequencies that I need.

```
match_table = read.table(file='donor_for.table', header=T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
freq        = read.table(file='frequency.table', header=T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fill_table <- function(FUN){     
  newfr <-freq
  for (country in rownames(freq)){
    for (type in colnames(freq)){
      newfr[country, type] <- FUN(country, type)
    }
  }
  return(newfr)
}

fill_table2 <- function(FUN){    
  newfr <-freq
  newfr[] <- outer(rownames(freq), colnames(freq), FUN=FUN)
  return(newfr)
}

find_donor <- function(country, type_receiver) {
  matches=colnames(match_table)[match_table[type_receiver,]==TRUE]
  return( sum(freq[country,matches]) )    #24
}
```

While `fill_table(find_donor)` works, `fill_table2(find_donor)`(which is supposed to do the same but more consise) yields:

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(freq, country, matches) : 
  undefined columns selected 
6 stop("undefined columns selected") 
5 `[.data.frame`(freq, country, matches) at blood.r#24
4 freq[country, matches] at blood.r#24
3 FUN(X, Y, ...) 
2 outer(rownames(freq), colnames(freq), FUN = FUN) at blood.r#18
1 fill_table2(find_donor)
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more explanation. Use `dput` to show some actual data and the output you'd like.

Comment: In the second function, you are using `FUN=round`, rounding works for numeric columns, here the rownames and column names are character.  Sorry, it is not clear.

Comment: @akrun I thought I'd need a default value for parameter `FUN`. Apparently I don't so I deleted it.